# JSON URL specific item to DIV

Tags: html, json

```
<html>
<script>
function gettodo()
{
    var TODOS ='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos';
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        url: TODOS,
        success: todos1
    });
}
setInterval(gettodo(),1000);
</script>


<div id="3rd_title_here"></div>
</html>
```

how do i display the 3rd title on the json url to the div

the title on the 3rd row is "fugiat veniam minus"

i want it to have like this when i execute the html

```
<div id="3rd_title_here">fugiat veniam minus</div>
```

to any ones curiousity this is what the JSON structure looks like if u view the URL link

```
{
"userId": 1,
"id": 1,
"title": "delectus aut autem",
"completed": false
},
{
"userId": 1,
"id": 2,
"title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
"completed": false
},
{
"userId": 1,
"id": 3,
"title": "fugiat veniam minus",
"completed": false
},
{
"userId": 1,
"id": 4,
"title": "et porro tempora",
"completed": true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you're getting is an array of todos, to get the third element in the array you have to use it's index which is 2.

You can achieve that by doing something like this.

```
<html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" 
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<script>
function gettodo()
{
    var TODOS ='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos';
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        url: TODOS,
        success: function(data) {  
          $('#3rd_title_here').html(data[2].title);
        }
    });
}
setInterval(gettodo(),1000);
</script>


<div id="3rd_title_here"></div>
</html>
```

Comment: hi i tested your code  it didnt work :( nothing displayed help needed badly

Comment: Are you getting any errors? check the console and show me the errors if you're getting any.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at gettodo (index2.html:6)
    at index2.html:15

the error :(

Comment: You're getting that error because you do not have jQuery, you can either link it to your html using the CDN or a local jquery file. I will edit the code to include the jQuery script.

Comment: btw i pasted this on the html and it worked
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: Okay, awesome! :)

Comment: hi joe i emailed you i need help badly :( on another json problem

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
function gettodo()
        {
            var TODOS ='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos';
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                url: TODOS,
                success: function(data) {
                   $("#3rd_title_here").html(data[2].title);
                }   
            });
        }
    setInterval(gettodo(),1000);
```

the `.html()` method of jquery renders the text into the html, just like what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: does it update real time to? i wanted a real time update every 1000 ms

Comment: how to get specific 3rd title?

Comment: You have a json object, what you need to do, is to get the 3rd title from the josn and use in the .html() method. You did not provide your json structure so I do not want to mislead you as to how to approach this 3rd title property.

Comment: hi the json structure is
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos
this one u can view it

Comment: this is because nothing is returning from the data, look at your json the debugger, see if there is any response.

Comment: it says on the error
"script.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at gettodo (script.js:4)
    at script.js:13"

Comment: your jquery reference didn't load

Answer (score 0):

```
function gettodo()
{
    var TODOS ='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos';
   var todos1 = $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        url: TODOS,
        success: function(data){
        return data;

}});
}
setInterval(gettodo(),1000);
</script>


<div id="3rd_title_here"></div>
</html>
```

then you do:

```
 $("#3rd_title_here").html(todos1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function gettodo()
{
    var TODOS ='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos';
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        url: TODOS,
        success: todos1
    });
}
setInterval(gettodo(),1000);

function todos1(data){
for (var i in data){
$('#titles').append('<div id="title_"'+i+'>'+data[i].title+'</div>');
}
}
});
```

And the HTML code will be like

```
<body>
<div id='titles'>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: @ lee sin, Do you want only third title?

Answer (score 0):

thx alot guys it works now :D
i just forgot to put jquery js

```
<html>
<head></head>
<div id="3rd_title_here"></div>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

JScript here

```
    function gettodo()
{
    var TODOS ='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos';
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: TODOS,
        success: function(data) {  
          $('#3rd_title_here').html(data[3].title);
        }
    });
}
setInterval(gettodo(),1000);
```